Launching Junit test in Eclipse failed. JAVA 21 Eclipse Version: 2024-09. ERROR : Reference to undefined variable jacocoSurefireArgLine
When i run a unit test using eclipse i get this error " Reference to undefined variable jacocoSurefireArgLine " but when runing tests using maven clean install test is passing good what may be the issue

JUnit works fine for me in Eclipse 2024-09. Please provide a minimal reproducible example (including a dummy test class and minimal pom.xml file).


And exactly which UI actions you're taking to launch your test.


If you show use your pom file. jacocoSurefireArgLine is something wrong.. but I can't tell for sure without more information... best would be an example project on Github or alike...

I have the same problem, since I hae upgraded to Eclipse 2024-09

@user3018906 Then please provide a minimal reproducible example by editing this question or if this question has already been close because of the missing reproducible example, by asking a new question.
